# Model binding and validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, fluentvalidation

I am developing a custom model binding in Asp.Net and I need to modify one value during the binding, and then pass the model to the fluent validator.
The code looks like this:

Validation:

```
    public MyValidator()
    {
        Custom(e =>
        {
            if (e.property != 1)
                return new ValidationFailure();

            return null;
        });
    }
```

Model binder:

```
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var model = base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext) as IMyEntity;

        model.property = 1;

        return model;
    }
```

The problem is that the validation is done during `base.BindModel` rather than at the end of the whole binding. For this reason the validation is always failing.

Is there any way to prevent the validation during the `base.BindModel` and wait for the binding to complete?

Comment: Why are you mixing responsibilities?  Binding should not be doing any validation.  Are you using [tag:asp.net-mvc]?  And if you're validating with fluentvalidation, why not just [just configure fluentvalidation in mvc automatically](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/wiki/h.-ASP.NET-MVC-5-integration)?

Comment: That's exactly the problem. The fluent validator is being called automatically during the binding. I want to prevent this.